# TypeScript - best syntax for adding new properties to a typed object without declaring a new interface?

Tags: typescript

I've been using TypeScript with Angular for half a year now. When I need to add something to the $scope, I follow the IMHO best practice of defining an interface like this:

```
interface IMyScope extends ng.ISCope { 
    myAddedProp:string;
}

...

link:($scope:IMyScope ){
    $scope.myAddedProp = "foo";
}
```

However, at times it would still be convenient to add properties to the $scope on the fly (mainly when I'm prototyping). For those cases I usually do something like this:

```
link:($scope:IScope ){

    (<any>$scope).myAddedProp = "foo";

    //or
    $scope["myAddedProp"] = "foo";

    //If I have to add many props, I use this:
    var $scopeA: any = $scope;
    $scopeA.myAddedProp1 = "foo";
    $scopeA.myAddedProp2 = "bar";
    $scopeA.myAddedProp3 = "baz";
}
```

I've also had this problem in NodeJS and other libraries - when you just need to add a few properties and don't want to bother with an interface.

SO search gives all those options, but isn't there a better way to do it? Something like

```
 $scope*.newProp = "foo";
```

?

Comment: You could do `$scope['myAddedProp'] = "foo";`

Comment: You've covered all the available options, basically.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a class on the scope:

```
interface IMyScope extends ng.ISCope { 
    vm:SomeClass;
}

link:($scope:IMyScope){

    scope.vm = new SomeClass();
}
```

Then you can just add new properties to `SomeClass` without a need to maintain an interface manually.

Even better use the `controller` option on the directive to setup a class for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic scope to get the VM strongly typed into the controller:

```
interface IScope<T> extends angular.IScope {
    vm: T;
}

class MyController {

    private vm: MyViewModel;

    static $inject = ['$scope'];
    constructor(scope: IScope<MyViewModel>) {

        super();

        this.vm = new MyViewModel();

        scope.vm = this.vm;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will also work for adding other strongly typed members to the scope.  I didn't need the type parameter and just extended IScope, then added the members I needed to the new interface.  then in the constructor I typed $scope as ILocalScope and it worked very well.